# How to strconv in echo c.param?

Tags: go, go-echo

Could anyone advise how to overcome this problem please ?

```golang
    func GetUserController(c echo.Context) error {
    id := c.Param("id")
    finduser := users[id]
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK,finduser)}

    var users []User

    type User struct {
    Id       int    `json:"id"`
    }`
```

Results in error:
`invalid argument: index id (variable of type string) must be integer`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: invalid argument: index id (variable of type string) must be integer

Comment: Have a look at this package from the standard lib https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#hdr-Numeric_Conversions

Answer (score 1):

it return type string, you should convert into int

```
id, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

c.Params always returns string. You are trying to use a string value for array index which is not possible.

```
finduser := users[id]
```

id is a string. It should be int value.

```
id := c.Param("id")
id, _ := strconv.Atoi(id)
// Check for err
finduser := users[id]
```